# Чем отличается RASP от RAM?

Tags: алгоритм, структуры-данных

Всем привет, я сейчас изучаю "Алгоритмы и структуры данных" и столкнулся с вопросом, ***чем отличается RASP от RAM?*** В гугле порылся, нашёл несколько статей. Прочитав их, я сделал такие выводы:

1. RAM - Random Access Machine - состоит из входной и выходной ленты и памятью
2. RASP - то же, что и RAM, но выполняемая программа находится в памяти, поэтому ее можно перезаписать.
3. Небольшое замечание, что RAM - это пример гарвардской архитектуры (память и инструкции отдельно), RASP - это пример архитектуры фон Неймана (память и инструкции в одной памяти)
4. RASP относится к RAM, как универсальная машина Тьюринга к обычной машине Тьюринга.

Я понимаю 4 вывод так:
RASP - это уникальная машина, которая может воспроизвести любой алгоритм RAM, перезаписывая код(инструкции).

Подправьте пожалуйста мои суждения и дополните, если я что-то не написал.

Comment: "Thus the RASP is to the RAM as the Universal Turing machine is to the Turing machine." [Random-access stored-program machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_stored-program_machine).